# Equivalence partitioning for method that calculates the number of roots of a polynomial

Tags: c, testing

I need help with assignment in Program Verification, where i have to find at least 5 equivalence classes for the method that gives the number of roots of a non-zero polynomial determined by the coefficients given as a parameter.

All i have is method signature "unsigned roots (float a0, ...)"
It takes at least one parameter.

All i can derive from specifications and method signature are 2 classes:
1. Valid - (at least parameter must be unequal zero)
2. Invalid - (the opposite, all parameters are equal zero)

How could i come up with 3 more equivalence classes?

Thanks

Comment: What is the method? What meaning has "number of roots"? Real roots, multiplicities, roots inside an interval,... What do you understand as "equivalence" of polynomials?

Comment: Number of roots means, real roots including their multiplicities.
Those are all information i have. There is no implementation of the method.
Im not sure i understand your last question.